# Drag From Iframe to Input [ASP.net]

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I would like to drag text  from an iframe to an input.
The Iframe contains a website.

```
<iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>
<input id="put" />
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: and what you have tried?

Comment: I tried to Drag some text to an Input in my PAGE.html
but i can't do that using src in an Iframe.